# Array is not saving when the app relaunches. Problem with persistent data

Tags: arrays, swift, save, persistence

I am trying to save an array and whenever I reload the app the array is empty.

I have tried userDefaults and core Data. Each time I build an array, it starts empty when I load the app. I'm unsure of where to save the array and if adding to the array through an IBAction is causing the problem

```
firstArray: [Double] = []
@IBAction func userSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
oneArray()
func oneArray(){

    if selected == "Breakfast" {



    if let firstArrays = Double(glucoseReading.text!) {

        //append new element to  Array
        firstArray.append(firstArrays)
        print(breakfastSugarsArray)
  }
}
}
```

I want to be able to save the array on app-relaunches and not have the array start empty each time the app is loaded. My problem may be I don't know where to save the array, or how to do it.

I want to be able to save the array on app-relaunches and not have the array start empty each time the app is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the `userSubmit(...)` is going to be triggered it will check the value of `selected` as in your example, check if there is some Double data in `glucosReading.text` and then retrieve your array saved in UserDefault and update it with the new values.

```
@IBAction func userSubmit(_ sender: Any) {    
   if selected == "Breakfast" {
       if let glucoseData = Double(glucoseReading.text!) {
           // retrieve from UserDefault if none create an empty array
           let glucoseListData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "glucoseListData") as? [Double] ?? [Double]()

           // store in UserDefault
           glucoseListData.append(glucoseData)
           UserDefaults.standard.set(glucoseListData, forKey: "glucoseListData")

           // check print outputs in Xcode logs
           println("Glucose data list: \(glucoseListData)")
       }
    }
}
```